# How old is Tuvok?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, age

In the episode "Meld", Tuvok mentions he has been studying violence for over 100 years, but in another episode Janeway gives him a birthday cake and say it will not be long before he hits the "big 3 digits".

Since these statements seem contradictory, how old is Tuvok?

Comment: Hi Darren.  Please also use the [tag:star-trek] tag on your questions, in addition to the more specific tags.  This will ensure that all Star Trek subscribers on the site will see your questions.  :-)

Comment: This issue [was discussed in the season 6 episode ‘Alice’](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Alice_(episode)#Continuity_and_trivia).

Comment: possibly its a case of calender differences, perhaps vulcan has a longer year than earth so while he is in human years 112 in vulcan years he's just like 95 or so (though that is admittedly just pure speculation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Voy: Flashback](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/225.htm), Tuvok was 29 when he was assigned to the USS Excelsior...

> **TUVOK:** *It's a long story, Captain, but suffice it to say, this was my first Starfleet career. I was twenty nine years old.*

... which places his birthdate somewhere around 2264 since we know (from the the [show script](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tuvok)) that the rescue attempt depicted in [Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102975/) took place some two months after he was assigned.

Taking into account that the events of [Fury](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fury_(episode)) took place in 2376, this would make him approximately **112** years old when Janeway celebrated his birthday (e.g **not 100**).

---

As far as I'm aware, there's no good explanation for this discontinuity other than that his records may be inaccurate (a distinct possibility given that Janeway is utterly unaware of his first Starfleet career) or that Janeway was simply mistaken (which seems unlikely).

There's also the slim possibility that with all the time travel they've been doing, Tuvok is actually ***111*** years of age, which would explain Janeway's "triple digits" comment.

Comment: Great answer, Richard.  There was also an [episode](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_(episode)) of *Voyager* where Tuvok was stranded on a planet where time elapsed differently, causing Tuvok and Paris to be a few months older than they should be.

Comment: I'm also fairly certain that "triple digits" universally means a number between 100 and 999 inclusive, not specifically triple *repeated* digits (111, 222, etc.)  It's simply a small discontinuity in the writing.

Comment: @praxis if Janeway's words are 'big three digits' she could be referring to any 'big three'

Answer (score 7):

The question "How old is Tuvok?" is flawed.  It cannot be answered unless you specify the date for which you would like to calculate his age.  A better question would be "When was Tuvok born?"

In Season 7, Episode 1, Tuvok

> is in the process of being assimilated on a BORG ship.  To delay his assimilation, Tuvok

recites certain facts about his own life.  At one point, he says that he was born on stardate 38774, on the Vulcanis Lunar Colony.

Comment: “In Season 7, Episode 1, Tuvok is in the process of being assimilated on a BORG ship.” Spoilers!

Answer (score 2):

If you do simple math from the year of Praxis' explosion (2293) and detract 29 (because at the time, Tuvok was 29 years old according to episode 'Flashback'), then according to this, Tuvok was born in 2264.

The episode in which Janeway gives Tuvok a birthday cake was called 'Fury'(Season 6, episode 23).
Since Voyager was launched in 2371, 'Fury' would have taken place in 2376 given that the earlier episode Muse has a stardate of 53896 (and Unimatrix Zero is the last episode in this season which has a stardate 54014) - there are 2 episodes between Fury and Unimatrix Zero (not enough time to place Fury in 2377).

That would make Tuvok 112 years years old in episode 'Fury'... and 108 years old in episode 'Meld'.

So, in this instance, Janeway seems to be wrong... and Tuvok's statement that he's been studying violence for over 100 years is accurate.

Not sure why he never corrected Janeway... but it could have been simply for the purpose of continuing to keep her in the dark.
After all, she implies in 'Fury' that it took 'exhausting research' to find out his age, and he wasn't exactly forthcoming with this data with everyone else (which is odd, considering that his SF record would have likely had this information).

Answer (score 0):

In the episode "Flashback" (S3E2) Tuvok has a mind meld flashback with Janeway.  When she asks him when this is, he says "about 80 years ago".  A little while later in the flashback, Janeway asks him about his star trek career and Tuvok mentions that at the time of this flashback is is 29.  Assumimg this is accurate, that means he is 109 years old by the second episode of season 3 of Voyager.

Comment: "About 80" could mean anything from maybe 77 to 83